# EditText cursor in top left position.

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using `EditText` for message. Height of `EditText` is `200dp`.

Problem is that when i click on this `EditText`, cursor is blinking on the middle of the `EditText`,while I want cursor should be blink in the top of the `EditText`.

Comment: set gravity top for EditText **android:gravity="top"**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

set gravity in edittext xml

```
android:gravity="top"
```

or in java code:-

```
editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

Answer (score 3):

Set gravity value as Top in your edittext like this :

```
android:gravity="top"
```

This will put cursor on top...

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the cursor position using:

`editText.setSelection(0);`

as well as setting the gravity to top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:gravity = "top"` in your layout.